# What does "The bargain to the letter" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *Dune* (2021), on the directions of Vladimir with a bargain to release his wife,
Dr Yeuh betrayed Duke Leto's family:

> Dr Yeuh: I jammed their comms and lowered their shields. I delivered
> the Duke and his family.
>
> Vladimir: **The bargain to the letter**. And what was I to do for you?
>
> Dr Yeuh: Deliver my wife from her agony.

What does "The bargain to the letter" mean?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Vladimir Harkonnen is dropping some words from the beginning of the phrase to make it sound more poetic.

What he's really saying, and would be understood is: "*[You have followed]* the bargain to the letter." Meaning that Yeuh has done exactly what was agreed upon when they made the initial bargain.

Comment: The full idiom is "the letter **of the law**" [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-letter-of-the-law), often contrasted with "the spirit of the law" [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_and_spirit_of_the_law). If you stick just to the letter, and not the spirit, then you may be criticised.

Comment: @NigelTouch That is the typical use of that phrase, but I don't think there's any contrast here. Vladimir isn't saying that Yueh did only what they had agreed, but didn't follow the spirit of the bargain. Interestingly, what the Harkonnen's do next is a perfect example of following the letter, but not the spirit of their agreement.

Comment: @NigelTouch No, "the letter" stands by itself as a phrase with this meaning. Colocation is not the same thing as idiom. One can follow the law, a contract, an agreement, a promise, an order, etc. "to the letter".

Comment: @NigelTouch: If I do something to the letter or [X]; you have no way of knowing if I also did something to the spirit of [X]. It is possible that doing something to the letter implies doing _more_ than the spirit (e.g. I crossed every t and dotted every I), _less_ than the spirit (e.g. I smile at customers as my employer requests, but it's clearly a fake smile), or _avoids_ the spirit (e.g. I smile at customers as my employer requests, but intentionally awkwardly). But none of those are inevitable, they are highly contextual and you cannot make any definitive statements here.

Comment: Saying an agreement was followed "to the letter" also *strongly* implies that it was at the same time violated in the spirit. In this case, the Baron is *expecting* Dr. Yueh to have done something out of bounds (the tooth, but he doesn't know that yet), and equally the Baron knows that *He* will be following the bargain to the letter, not the spirit, by "freeing" Yueh's wife through killing her.

Answer (score 17):

As others have indicated, the statement means that he completed his side of the bargain exactly as detailed. However, following something to the letter often includes the implication that you have violated the spirit of the agreement while conforming to the exact requirements. Vladimir makes this statement to Yeuh because he has also conformed to the letter of the bargain. Specifically, he has delivered Yeuh's wife from agony - by killing her. If she is dead, she is not in agony and so the Baron has fulfilled the letter of the bargain. Generally, it would be assumed that delivering her from agony would mean to release her from captivity and torture. (Yeuh makes it clear that he was not fooled by the Baron's duplicity and fully expected the Baron to kill her.)

It is common to see this usage of the phrase when saying that something conforms to the letter of the law.

Comment: +1. Your extra detail is vital to fully understanding it. Suggest you integrate some sources.  "The letter of the law" [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-letter-of-the-law). "Letter and spirit of the law" [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_and_spirit_of_the_law).

Answer (score 14):

[Merriam-Webster *to the letter*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%20the%20letter)

> exactly or precisely
> *obey the law to the letter*

Vladimir is affirming that what Dr. Yeuh has just claimed he did was **exactly according to the bargain** that they had previously made.